# Fonte em negrito CSS Duvida Basica

Tags: css, css3

Oi, estou tentando colar a fonte mais grossa, porém não consegui até onde sei o codigo font-weight: faria isso.

Quando uso:

```
font-weight: 500;
```

A fonte fica normal, mais quando uso:

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Quero ir fazendo a fonte ficar mais grossa aos poucos e o **bold** faz isso de uma só forma.
Onde que há de errado? Seria a font ou o codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez você não veja alteração porque a diferença do 400 (normal) para o 500 é pequena. O bold equivale a 700. Veja neste [link](https://htmldog.com/references/css/properties/font-weight/) a aparência das fontes para cada weight e observe a similaridade de 400 e 500.

Comment: Obg era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem nada de errado no seu código. 
Não se nota grande diferença entre font-weight: 300 e 500. Se aumentar o valor, irá ver diferenças no bold